# Valid number how to traverse char inside argv array

Tags: c

Im trying to do a nested loops to iterate through the characters that I pass through into argv.
Lets say I pass multiple args into the command line like 10 30 50 60
I want to do something like this:

```
void isValid(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int len = strlen(argv[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j ++)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[i][0], "-") == 0)
            {
                printf("- is the first character in index in the first argument");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Im getting a warning however that  passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast.
So is this the correct way to iterate through using nested loop? is there a different method that is correct? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `argv[i][0]` is a single character, so you could write `if (argv[i][0] == '-')` to compare it.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with the `j` loop. Please explain.

Comment: You should get a warning for that `strcmp()` call. The arguments to `strcmp()` both have to be strings, not characters.

Answer (score 2):

C strings are null terminated character arrays. Characters are not just single character strings as they are in other languages. Use **single quotes** to specify a character literal instead of a string, and this can be compared against the first character of the string:

```
if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
    printf("- is the first character in index in the first argument");
}
```